# 2-D array reading from external file

Tags: java

this is my java code for comparing MCQ answers with the answer key in the main function, where students responses are stored in an external .txt file. It does show me an output but it's not the correct one. Below is my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  char [] answer = new char[152];
  //char[] answer = new char[10];
        char[] keys = {'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D'};

  int c = 0;
  try{

     Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("students1.txt"));
     while(data.hasNextchar())
     {
        String s = data.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i+=2) {
           if(s.charAt(i) == keys[count])
            count++;

        }

      System.out.println("Student " +c + "'s correct count is " + count);
      c++;

     }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
  }


  In the Output Window it should show
   Student 1's correct count is 7
   Student 2's correct count is 7
   Student 3's correct count is 7
   Student 4's correct count is 6
   Student 5's correct count is 5
   Student 6's correct count is 4
   Student 7's correct count is 8
   Student 8's correct count is 7
```

Comment: What is the "correct one"? Please edit your question to include the file

Comment: second one is the correct one'

Comment: Provide the format of the file .txt

Comment: Student 0's correct count is7
Student 1's correct count is6
Student 2's correct count is5
Student 3's correct count is4
Student 4's correct count is8
Student 5's correct count is7
Student 6's correct count is7
Student 7's correct count is7

Comment: B B A C C D E E A D 
E B E C C D E E A D
A B A C C D E E A D
D B A B C A E E A D
E D D A C B E E A D
C B A E D C E E A D 
A B D C C D E E A D 
B B E C C D E E A D

Comment: That's the value of .txt file where each alphabet is the answer from the student and each student has 10 answers, so there are 8 students and 80 alphabets representing 10 alphabet answer per student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop (Edit: might) be the culprit:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i+=2) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == keys[count])
        count++;
    }
}
```

Because you are checking the answer key at count in `keys[count]` you are only looking at the right part of the answer key when they get every question right.

Instead try something like:

```
if (s.charAt(i) == keys[i/2]) {
    count++;
}
```

With that change to the if inside the for loop, you now are checking the next answer in the key every time the loop executes, instead of only if the answer to the previous question was correct.

I can't guarantee that this will work because your comment with the input didn't have the newlines in it so I couldn't validate if it got the right results.

I hope this helps!

Edit: I made another change. I changed `data.hasNextchar()` to `data.hasNextLine()` and here's a sample text input file and output

```
char[] keys = {'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D'};
```

students1.txt

```
D A D C C D A E A D
D A D D A D A E A D
D A D C C D A B A D
D A D D D D E C A D
```

if statement:

```
if(s.charAt(i) == keys[i/2])
    count++;
```

Output:

```
Student 0's correct count is 9
Student 1's correct count is 7
Student 2's correct count is 8
Student 3's correct count is 5
```

I think that this is working properly.

Comment: It works partially, but it shows me result of 11 students instead of just 8, where 3 students marks are just 0

Comment: Okay - I'm sorry that it only works partially. Could you edit your original question to include the text with line breaks? I could probably figure out the error easier that way.

Comment: I dont' know how to upload a text file in comment here. please may you guide me. I am very new here

Comment: I have edited my question. Thank you very much, at least that code works partial

Comment: Are you separating each student's individual answers with a whitespace ` ` and separating each student with a line break in your `students.txt` file?

Comment: If you had extra lines at the bottom of your text file, even empty lines that could be causing the 3 students with zero marks. The loop would recognize those empty lines but not read any answers and consider the 3  (nonexistent) students as having a zero score.

Comment: @david Works Perfectly fine now. Thank You very much. Really appreciate your quick responses and quick help. Thank you again.